# Format specific cell to date with python in google sheet API V4

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-api

I try to format some cells to a date format in a google spreadsheet.

The data on the cell looks like this : **09/11/2021**
And I try to make it looks like this : **11/2021**
Or at least format the cell with a date format.

I use **batchUpdate()** to update cells :
`request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()`

#### What I tried :

- Both **updateCells** and **repeatCell** but none worked.
- Formatting before AND after adding the value to the cell.
- Change cells by changing **rown** or **coln** values (in the code below)
- Other date formats like `dd-mm-yy` or `mm yyyy`
- Also read a lot of google documentation and watched their videos...

#### updateCells body

```
        body = {
            "requests": [
                {
                'updateCells': {
                    'range': {
                        'sheetId': sheet_id,
                        'startRowIndex': rown-1,
                        'endRowIndex': rown,
                        'startColumnIndex': coln,
                        'endColumnIndex': coln
                    },
                    'rows': {'values': [{'userEnteredFormat': {'numberFormat': {'type': "DATE", 'pattern': "mm/yyyy"}}}]},
                    'fields': 'userEnteredFormat.numberFormat'
                }
                }
            ]
        }
```

#### repeatCell body

```
         body = {
            "requests": [
                {
                    "repeatCell": {
                        "range": {
                            "sheetId": sheet_id,
                            "startRowIndex": rown-1,
                            "endRowIndex": rown,
                            "startColumnIndex": coln,
                            "endColumnIndex": coln
                        },
                        "cell": {
                            "userEnteredFormat": {
                                "numberFormat": {
                                    "type": "DATE",
                                    "pattern": "mm/yyyy"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "fields": "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Any tips and tricks or ideas are welcome !

Comment: Have you tried using json.dumps() to the body before using it in batchUpdate()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought that in your request body, the reason of your issue might be due to that the values of `'startColumnIndex': coln,` and `'endColumnIndex': coln` are the same. So, for example, how about modifying your request bodies as follows?

#### For `updateCells body`:

```
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            'updateCells': {
                'range': {
                    'sheetId': sheet_id,
                    'startRowIndex': rown-1,
                    'endRowIndex': rown,
                    'startColumnIndex': coln-1, # Modified
                    'endColumnIndex': coln
                },
                'rows': {'values': [{'userEnteredFormat': {'numberFormat': {'type': "DATE", 'pattern': "mm/yyyy"}}}]},
                'fields': 'userEnteredFormat.numberFormat'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### For `repeatCell body`:

```
body = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "repeatCell": {
                "range": {
                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                    "startRowIndex": rown-1,
                    "endRowIndex": rown,
                    "startColumnIndex": coln-1, # Modified
                    "endColumnIndex": coln
                },
                "cell": {
                    "userEnteredFormat": {
                        "numberFormat": {
                            "type": "DATE",
                            "pattern": "mm/yyyy"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Note:

- In above modified request body, for example, when the values of `rown` and `coln` are `1` and `1`, respectively, the number format of cell "A1" is modified.
- In this modified script, it supposes that the value of `09/11/2021` in the cell is the date object. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)
- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tanaike ! I tried to change the start value with -1, but nothing changed. I also tried with removing the start index for rows as it is proposed in the google documentation, but still see no changes. I print the values of coln and rown and they seems good

Comment: @Bruuuh Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. At first, in my answer, it supposes that the cell value of `09/11/2021` is the date object. How about this? If you cannot understand about it, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. Because when I tested above modification, I can confirm that the script works and the number format can be modified. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: That's good, you were right ! The format of the date was bad, I was sending string. I replaced it directly with something like `datetime.strptime(myDate, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%d/%m/%y")` and this is working ! Thanks a lot @Tanaike :)

Comment: @Bruuuh Thank you for replying and adding more information. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.